# How to find the derivative of $\frac{1}{x^3}$ by definition of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^3}$$
>   Find the derivative of $f$ by using the derivative definition.

I have tried several pages of working, but nothing seemed to work until I actually used the quotient rule (definitions of derivative are soo complicated lol).

Comment: If you expand the denominators to get a common denominator and simplify, you should be able to cancel an $h$ out from the numerator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that using the binomial theorem, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\frac1{(x+h)^3}-\frac1{x^3}}{h}&=\frac{x^3-(x+h)^3}{hx^3(x+h)^3}\\\\
&=\frac{-3x^2h-3xh^2-h^3}{hx^3(x+h)^3}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity
$a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$
after using a common denominators.